# Select from two tables, based on 2 columns one of which must not be distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Say I have 2 tables, one storing info on items, and second one used for tracking various quantities linked to said item.

My item has an order number, id number and an lot number. The quantities from second table I'm interested in are "quantity ready" (how many I have in stock), "quantity ordered" (how many clients have ordered) and "quantity shipped" (how many I sent already). Both tables have more data, but I don't need it for this query.

What I want: a query that will return to me all order numbers which contain items that have more than one lot number (so if an item has only a single distinct lot number, I don't want it in results), which I already have some of (so qty_ready > 0) and which I shipped some, but not all of my order (so qty_shipped < qty_ordered).

Example:

Table Item:

```
+-------+--------+------------------+
| IdNum | LotNum | Someothercolumns |
+-------+--------+------------------+
|     1 | 10-00  |              123 |
|     2 | 10-01  |              123 |
|     2 | 10-02  |              123 |
|     3 | 10-03  |              123 |
|     3 | 10-04  |              123 |
+-------+--------+------------------+
```

Table ItemQty:

```
+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----+
| orderNum | idNum   | qty_ready | qty_ordered | qty_shipped |other|
+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----+
| O1       |       1 |        10 |           5 |           3 | 123 |
| O2       |       2 |        10 |          10 |          10 | 123 |
| O3       |       2 |        10 |           5 |           3 | 123 |
| O4       |       3 |         0 |          10 |           5 | 123 |
| O5       |       3 |         0 |           5 |           5 | 123 |
+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----+
```

Here I would want only `O3` and it's data returned, since:

- `O1` - item `1` has only a single `lot` associated with it
- `O2` - item `2` has more than one `lot`, but the order is already completed
  (10 ordered and 10 sent)
- `O4` - item `3` has more than one lot, but
  `qty_ready` is not > 0
- `O5` - item `3` has more than one lot, but
  `qty_ready` is not > 0 and it is already completed (5 ordered and 5
  sent)

Here is my try at the query - although it returns the data, it does return many duplicate rows (if an item has 4 lots, I would get each result 4 times, so 16 rows). I suspect my joins are the problem, but I can't seem to find it:

```
;with noo as (select count(LotNum) over(partition by LotNum) as temp,  Item.* 
from Item
inner join ItemQty on ItemQty.idNum = Item.idNum 
where Item.idNum in 
(select t1.idNum 
from Item t1
inner join Item t2 on t1.idNum = t2.idNum 
where t1.LotNum <> t2.lotNum) and qty_shipped < qty_ordered and qty_ready > 0)
select * from noo where temp > 1
order by idNum desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from itemqty
where idnum in 
(select idnum from item group by idnum having count(*) > 1)
and qty_ready > 0
and qty_ordered > qty_shipped
and qty_shipped > 0
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb994/4)